# Laravel contains method not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a Many to Many relation between User and Role. For some strange reason when I do `User::find(1)->roles->contains(2)` it just won't work, always throws `false` (I've checked in the db and indeed user with id 1 has role with id 2).

I'm using it just as the Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#collections

I dug the `contains()` method and found it in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collecion.php`, here it is:

```
/**
 * Determine if a key exists in the collection.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function contains($key, $value = null)
{
    if (func_num_args() == 1 && ! $key instanceof Closure)
    {
        $key = $key instanceof Model ? $key->getKey() : $key;

        return $this->filter(function($m) use ($key)
        {
            return $m->getKey() === $key;

        })->count() > 0;
    }
    elseif (func_num_args() == 2)
    {
        return $this->where($key, $value)->count() > 0;
    }

    return parent::contains($key);
}
```

Right in the middle of the method, if I change `return $m->getKey() === $key;` for `==` it suddenly works. Is this a typo? Should I report it in the repository or make a pull request?

P.S. It will never enter the `parent::contains()`, or at least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you have the wrong MySQL plugin installed in your PHP. There are two versions: `mysqlnd` and `libmysql`. The second one used to cause so much trouble for me, because it returns data from database as strings even if the value is an actual integer. The `mysqlnd` is correctly returning the value as integer so if you use `$model->id === 2` it will work correctly while with `libmysql` it will evaluate to false since it is strict check and `$model->id` will become `string '2'`. So this is what I would check your code against. Try to dump one of your roles ids and check if it is integer or string.

Comment: Oh wow, what you're saying is actually true for my case, it does throw something like `"id" => "1"`. So how am I supposed to change from `libmysql ` to `mysqlnd`?

Comment: It depends on what system you are using. Just try to search for ```enable mysqlnd {your operating system}``` with uncle Google and you should be fine. If you still can't find it, let us know.